# using helper methods in a view in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

there is something that is disturbing me a bit about rails 3.
i am trying to upgrade my application from rails 2 to rails 3.

i followed all the steps necessary to do and things were working well for me till now except one thing:

i have a helper method that is defined differently in different helpers, for example it is defined  in the application_helper in one way  and the same method defined in a different way in the homepage_helper, and defined differently in another helper, let's say video_helper, in addition to that, it is used in a shared view that is used throughout the application, now if i am in the homepage, i want this function to get called from the homepage_helper and if i am in the video page, the function must be called from the video_helper, based on the concept of convention in rails, this worked perfectly in rails 2 but in rails 3, the function is always called from the last helper, alphabetically ordered, that is in the example, video_helper.

How can i fix this?
Kindly advice.

Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3 all helpers are always loaded.

You can either:

1) name your helpers differently.

2) Explicity define which helpers you want

3) Check the controller from the helpers to determine which helper to provide.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, finally someone answered me :) option 1 will not work for my code, but how can i try the other two options? I tried including the helper methods but not one way worked for me, appreciate your help

Comment: For method 2, use `clear_helpers` and then specify the helpers you want to include as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your post right, you have something like

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def error_messages
    ...
  end
end

module VideoHelper
  def error_messages
    ...
  end
end

module HomepageHelper
  def error_messages
    ...
  end
end
```

And now you want to call error_messages from a specific helper and calling error_messages arbitrarily behaves differently from how it did in Rails 2.  Am I right so far?  If not, you can ignore the rest of this post =P

I just spent half an hour playing with the syntax and one of my projects in irb and the closest I could get was something along the lines of Posts::PostsHelper.helper_method, which works in irb if I 'include PostsHelper' first.

With that said, if you're willing to do something like Class::ClassHelper.helper_method, why not just rename "helper_method" so that it's unique to your ClassHelper?  You're going to have to change each "helper_method" call to be specific to some helper anyways.  I think this is a much cleaner solution